# WebSphere wsadmin ClassNotFound Exceptions

Tags: reflection, websphere, jython, classnotfoundexception, wsadmin

I'm trying to use wsadmin with Jython to deploy an EAR file.  Before the actual deployment, I need to run a DB update using a Java class.  I'm running into a ClassNotFoundException that isn't making sense to me.

Background:
The EAR file is exploded.  The wsadmin tool is started with the following options:

```
-wsadmin_classpath %CP%
-javaoption -Dpython.path=%CP%
```

Both of those point to the same classpath, which contains all necessary JARs.

The jython script gets a connection to a database, and calls a utility class to create a database script.  The utility class uses reflection to load other classes from the classpath (that is a hard-and-fast requirement of the library we are using, it can't be changed).  It basically looks like this:

```
from liquibase import Liquibase

def main(args):
    conn = getConnection(args)
    updater = Liquibase(conn)
    updater.update()
```

During the update() method, Liquibase uses reflection to instantiate some Java classes.  This is where I get a ClassNotFoundException, for example ClassNotFoundException: com.foo.CustomUpdate

In my script, I can import the com.foo.CustomUpdate class and get no errors:

```
from com.foo import CustomUpdate
c = CustomUpdate("select 1")
print c.getUpdate()
```

So I know that the class is on the classpath.  My only idea is that it has something to do with the reflection aspect of the library we are using.  Has anybody else run up against anything like this?

My only other idea, if the above is unfixable, is to split things out into a shell script and use Java to run the DB update and then wsadmin to deploy the EAR.